# Is it a good practice to add prefixes to all css classes?

Tags: css

Is it a good practice to add prefixes to all css classes to avoid conflicts with possible third party widgets/CMS/etc? Isn't this bad as it adds to file size ?
 How far should I go ? For example if my name is John Doe and I work on a business theme should I use JDBT-menu?
 Any article on this subject would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Best practice type questions are subjective and therefore off-topic for SO.

Comment: lol best practice isn't subjective....

Comment: Like with any global namespace, it's always best to avoid contamination, but it depends on the situation. I would not prefix every class as a rule of thumb. For example, hierarchy helps to avert contamination.

Comment: @leblma Best practice is usually a matter of opinion and subject to debate and POV.

Comment: generally it's a good practice, but it's not mandatory, depends by the situation.

Comment: @leblma - as you can see by the answers already posted, it's obviously subjective...

Comment: Filesize isn't a problem (gzipping the same prefix again and again = perfect case); selector performance isn't either (a parent class - on the left part of a selector - is performant enough and a page sould have thousands of elements or rules before it'd slow down by a few ms...) but these 2 points considered, did you encountered a problem in a project? And if you did, what caused it: too much conflicting frameworks? Would a better thought framework like PURE help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion, it's a very good idea to prefix CSS class names, along with implementing a strategy to follow logical naming conventions.

Whilst prefixes can be considered overkill for small projects, the lack of proper CSS namespace support can lead to conflicts on larger projects, especially when using third-party libraries. You can easily avoid such conflicts by prefixing CSS classes with your initials or a short abbreviation of your project name. Even on large CSS files you are only likely to add a few hundred bytes, and there are much better ways of minimising file size.

Take a look at the free online book, Scalable and Modular Architecture for CSS, for advice on CSS naming best practices. http://smacss.com

Comment: best answer for smacss tip

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't think is a bad idea. It may come in handy for future developers working on the project, if they can identify your code from the CMS/Framework code nice and easy.

I work a lot with Bootstrap, and I always use prefix.

Comment: And as leblma said, it should be a HUGE project for the size to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple.

I would do it, because the increased file size isn't significant to me. Unless you have thousands of css classes, it won't make a noticeable difference. Minify your css and you should not have any issue with css file size (it will have really low impact on your bandwith).

But obviously, if you don't use any other party css, you shouldn't use that.